# Converting API Example From C# To VB For DoL API

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to convert this sample code from the US Department of Labor API documentation from C# to VB (very cool if I can get it to work. Check it out [here](http://developer.dol.gov/DotNetSamples.htm)). I am **not** making the MVC example. When I use any online converters I get error:

```
-- line 1 col 11: invalid TypeDecl
```

This is the C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AgencyEntities entity = new AgencyEntities(new Uri(“http://api.dol.gov/V1/DOLAgency”));
        entity.SendingRequest += new EventHandler<SendingRequestEventArgs>(DOLDataUtil.service_SendingRequest);
        AgenciesView.DataSource = entity.Agencies;
        AgenciesView.DataBind();
    }
```

How can I get this wired up in VB?
When I did a line by line change using the VB Page_Load I get this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim entity As New AgencyEntities(New Uri("http://api.dol.gov/V1/DOLAgency"))

    entity.SendingRequest += New EventHandler(Of SendingRequestEventArgs)(DOLDataUtil.service_SendingRequest)
    AgenciesView.DataSource = entity.Agencies
    AgenciesView.DataBind()

End Sub
```

But, the line

```
entity.SendingRequest += New EventHandler(Of SendingRequestEventArgs)(DOLDataUtil.service_SendingRequest)
```

fails with several errors:

> - Error   1   'Public Event SendingRequest(sender As Object, e As
>     System.Data.Services.Client.SendingRequestEventArgs)' is an event, and
>     cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an
>     event.
> - Error   2   Delegate 'System.EventHandler(Of
>     System.Data.Services.Client.SendingRequestEventArgs)' requires an
>     'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to
>     its constructor.

What am I missing here?

Comment: take a look at AddHandler: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Did check that out before but it is, honestly, Greek to me. Trying to wrap my head around it and the simple examples on MSDN never really explain things to my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the offending line with:

```
AddHandler entity.SendingRequest, AddressOf DOLDataUtil.service_SendingRequest
```

And see if that helps...VB doesn't support that "+" syntax for adding event handlers.

Comment: Gives error on (DOLDataUtil.service_SendingRequest) that "Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Public Shared Sub service_SendingRequest(send As Object, e As System.Data.Services.Client.SendingRequestEventArgs)". Also that 'sender' is not specified.

Comment: I removed the "()" from around DOLDataUtil.service_SendingRequest and it is working now.

Comment: If you edit the answer to remove the () I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Meta-Knight :) Got called away and couldn't make the fix!